# What is the correct way to change the active Drupal theme programmatically?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-themes

What is the correct way to change the active Drupal theme programmatically?

Comment: What do you mean by "changing a theme programmatically". Customize a downloadable theme for a site? Alter the theme without modyfying it's files or something else?

Comment: Edited question to clarify. What I meant was how do I change the active theme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit: here is a simpler example.**

It uses Garland regardless of the theme setting. Note that this overrides the admin theme setting too.

```
function MODULENAME_init(){
    global $custom_theme;
    $custom_theme = 'garland';
}
```

---

**Edit: changing globally.**

And if you meant changing the theme setting in the database instead of just on the current page, here is how:

```
// Changes the theme to Garland
variable_set('theme_default', 'garland');

// Changes only the administration theme to Garland
variable_set('admin_theme', 'garland');
```

Comment: The global $custom_theme variable is probably what you're looking for, but it should be modified early enough for the whole page to use only one theme, and hook_init is a good location to do that.

Comment: What if you just want to make the admin theme active?